# Why RealmCollectionType methods return Results and not RealmCollectionType/AnyRealmCollection?

Tags: swift, realm

I recently moved from `Array` to `RealmCollectionType` because it provides more effective filters. Now I want to migrate my unit-tests as well, but I don't like the In-memory Realm because it requires me to setup a lot of links and relations between my objects. I was trying to mock `Results` and `LinkingObjects` by conforming my mock to `RealmCollectionType`. Unfortunately, I'm stuck implementing `filter` operation because it should return `Results` which is declared as `final`.

What is the purpose of filters to narrow it's return type to `Results`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`RealmCollection.filter(...)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Protocols/RealmCollection.html#/s:FP10RealmSwift15RealmCollection6filterFtSSGSaP___GCS_7Resultswx7Element_) returns a `Results` because that's the query result container in Realm. It does share some common interface elements with other collection types in Realm (like `LinkingObjects` and `List`), which is why it conforms to the `RealmCollection` protocol.

If you'd like to test code that's generic on say the `Collection` protocol in the Swift standard library, which `RealmCollection` inherits from, you can do so.

Comment: How can I make sure my filters going to use Realm predicate filtering and not Swift closures? Because the latter will require all objects to load in memory and I don't want that. Same thing with `sorted` methods.

Comment: The Swift standard library doesn't have `filter` and `sorted` methods that take `NSPredicate`s or query strings, so there's no risk of that happening.

Comment: That means if I implement them for `CollectionType`, this will hide efficient Realm implementation.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer because you did answered the question literally. I would request you to highlight some, maybe, political reasons of `RealmCollectionType` to return `Results` and not `RealmCollectionType`. I also offer to continue talk about `CollectionType` in [chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125679/realm-cocoaswift--how-to-write-logic-to-be-agnostic-to-collection-type-and-s)

Comment: `RealmCollection.filter()` never returns anything other than `Results` though, so to say that it returns a `RealmCollection` would be misleading, plus due to how Swift protocols work, you wouldn't be able to store the return value in a stored property, you'd need to wrap it with `AnyRealmCollection`. Let's take a step back and review what you're trying to do. If you can share some code that shows how you'd like things to work, maybe I can offer an alternative?

Comment: That's exactly what I did in [chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125679/realm-cocoaswift--how-to-write-logic-to-be-agnostic-to-collection-type-and-s)